# Pointers in Visual C++ Classes

Tags: .net, pointers, visual-c++, memory-management, c++-cli

I am updating a program written by someone else in C++/CLI to control a variety of different cameras. This program uses a class to control each camera type. My class is called ZylaDriver. I am fairly new to C++ and C++/CLI, so thank you in advance for your help and patience.

The SDK for the camera I am using has one function,AT_QueueBuffer(), to allocate memory to read data into. Once an image has been acquired, AT_WaitBuffer() can be used to return a pointer to the acquired data.

I would like to have two separate class functions which call these functions, ZylaDriver::expose(), and ZylaDriver::readImage(UInt16 * Buffer).

However, I am running into problems with memory access going between functions. As it stands, the code below produces a System.AccessViolationException when I attempt to assigned to Strideless_Buffer in ZylaDriver::readImage().

I believe that my problem is possibly related to deficiencies in my understanding of how managed memory works in C++/CLI. Or perhaps more basic deficiencies in my understanding of memory management in C++.

ZylaDriver.h:

```
#include "Driver.h"
#include "atcore.h"

ref class ZylaDriver : Driver {
public:
    ZylaDriver();
    ~ZylaDriver();
    virtual void expose(String^ Mode) override;
    virtual void readImage(UInt16 *buffer, String^ Mode) override;
protected:
    unsigned char* TestBufferPtr;
};
```

ZylaDriver.cpp

```
 #include "ZylaDriver.h"
 #include "atcore.h"

 using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
 ZylaDriver::ZylaDriver(){};
 ZylaDriver::~ZylaDriver(){};

 void ZylaDriver::expose(String^ Mode){
     if (Mode == "Normal){
        AT_64 ImageSizeBytes;
        AT_GetInt(*pcamera, L"ImageSizeBytes", &ImageSizeBytes);
        int BufferSize = static_cast<int>(ImageSizeBytes);
        //Create buffer(s) to store acquisition.
        TestBufferPtr = new unsigned char[BufferSize];
        AT_QueueBuffer(*pcamera, TestBufferPtr, BufferSize);
        AT_Command(*pcamera, L"AcquisitionStart");
      }
 }

 void ZylaDriver::readImage(UInt16 *buffer, String^ Mode){

    //Remove padding at the end of image rows, and handle 16bit deep Zyla images.
    if (Mode == "Normal"){
        AT_64 ImageSizeBytes;
        AT_GetInt(*pcamera, L"ImageSizeBytes", &ImageSizeBytes);
        int BufferSize = static_cast<int>(ImageSizeBytes);

        unsigned char * BufferPointer;
        AT_WaitBuffer(*pcamera, &BufferPointer, &BufferSize, AT_INFINITE);

        int rows = getRows();
        int cols = getCols();
        int ImageSize = static_cast<int>(ImageSizeBytes);

        AT_64 bytesPerRow;
        AT_GetInt(*pcamera, L"AOISTride", &bytesPerRow);
        int stride_bytes = static_cast<int>(bytesPerRow)-2 * rows;
        //remove useless data added by camera       
        unsigned char * Strideless_Buffer = new unsigned char[2 * rows*cols];
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < 2 * cols; x++){
                Strideless_Buffer[x + y * 2 * cols] = BufferPointer[x + y*bytesPerRow];
            }
        }
        //Converting array of 1-byte data to 2-byte pixels.
        UInt16* ImageBuffer_int = new UInt16[rows*cols];
        memcpy(ImageBuffer_int, Strideless_Buffer, 2 * rows*cols);
        //Simplicio assumes row counting starts at the top, Andor software assumes
        //it starts at the bottom. Need to flip image here for consistancy.
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
                buffer[x + y*cols] = ImageBuffer_int[x + (rows - y - 1)*cols];
            }
        }
        delete[] Strideless_Buffer;
        delete[] ImageBuffer_int;
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything or add information.

Comment: Making a char* a member of a C++/CLI class is **not** a problem.  Initialize it in the constructor and cleanup in both the destructor *and* the finalizer.

Comment: @HansPassant that much I do understand. I've updated my post to explain more clearly the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

> I can create a class member pointer (which was what I tried first), but this can be moved around by the GC. But AT_QueueBuffer doesn't know that. So when I try to access the buffer from another class function, I find uninitialized memory. My second attempt was to use a pin_ptr, but these cannot be class members.

That was regarding to this piece of code:

```
//Create buffer to store acquired data.
unsigned char * UserBuffer = new unsigned char[BufferSize];
```

Now I'm not sure how you picture C++/CLI to work, but that's an unmanaged block of memory. It will never "move around". It is also not "deallocated after expose() finishes".

I don't doubt you may have a problem, but your analysis is completely wrong. Perhaps post an actual working example that demonstrates it instead of trying to guess what it is.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on the question rather than an answer.

Comment: @Blindy that comment in my question wasn't referring to the line of code you quote. I will try and reconstruct my previous attempt.

Comment: I was referring to a pointer that is a class member. I will update my post with code better illustrating my problem later today.

Comment: Nothing changed with your edit, it won't "go out of scope" if it's a field in a class. I maintain that you're chasing wild horses with the real problem sitting pretty behind your hidden top-secret code. I don't even know what language you got that from, in C++ (which you said you know) dynamically allocated memory isn't automatically deallocated when the pointer "goes out of scope". And since it's unmanaged memory you can't say it's from managed C++ or C# (or Java) either.

Comment: Hi Blindy, I haven't finished my edit. I posted the code I currently have. I am working on putting up some code that illustrates my problem. I recognize that I have a number of misunderstandings about how managed code works.